# How do I get the Windows 10 version and build number?

Tags: c#, .net-4.6

How can I get the version / build number of a Windows 10 machine? This application running on Windows builds prior to Windows 10 "RTM" will be handled one way, after will be handled a different way.

Comment: Google broken today?